# Editing an HTML-based newsletter in the browser - "page inside a page" design pattern

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, iframe, user-interface, html-email

I am building an app allowing users to build their own email newsletters based on predefined templates.

I have a page showing the project name etc. and the newsletter laid out within it. For this one I am using an iframe as it seemed to be the simplest solution.

```
application page
    iframe
        html template with html content
```

Now that I am working on the editing pages, however, I am starting to doubt that iframe is the solution for this situation.

On the editing page, I want to show an editor embedded within the body of the newsletter template, so the users can edit the editable area in place, while still seeing the template. Also, I want to show them a preview before they save the new version.

So, the editing screen would look something like:

```
application page
    html template containing the editable area
        ckeditor allowing editing the editable area
```

Now, if I use an iframe for the editable view, then the ckeditor would have to be embedded inside the iframe. And, if I submit the iframe, then the application page does not refresh. This solution and workarounds seem overly complex/overengineerred.

```
application page
    iframe
        html template containing the editable area
           ckeditor allowing editing the editable area
```

So, what would another solution be?

I am thinking of taking the newsletter template's CSS styles and body tag content and displaying them within the app page. I would have to make sure the styles are defined uniquely for the app to avoid them clashing with newsletter styles, which may be doable. Also I have control over the templates and will be able to identify areas to be merged into the page body.

```
application page
    merged html template css
    html template body tag content 
        ckeditor allowing editing the editable area
```

This feels a little fragile to me as I'd have to dynamically extract the styles and body tag contents and am not sure they would display 100% correctly in the application page.

I imagine this is a fairly common pattern and am wondering how others have solved the issue, or how would you solve it?

Especially wondering if there may be a change in design which would simplify the process and technical solution.

I am building this in Rails 3.2.

Comment: In my opinion it is always best to hand code html emails as the amount of things that can go wrong in terms of layout is phenomenal

Comment: Thank you. This is a case where HTML templates are hand-coded, but then there are dozens of changes to the content. So I am providing access to editing the content only.

Answer (score 0):

I built something very similar to this. I considered using a WYSIWYG editor like FCK, but it was too much hassle telling it to remove its own styles, or calculating the rendered style of a text node.

Instead, I used the `contenteditable` attribute on any relevant elements.

On the backend, the iframe constantly writes to the server when a change is made. Potentially you could use HTML5 storage to do this instead, and then you could reduce the frequency of AJAX calls.

This way, you have complete control over the styles, and how they are applied.